# Is their any solution for an error of mozilla central describe below?

Tags: mozilla, mozilla-prism

I am installing mozilla browzer which runs on local host(offline). For that i install mozilla build setup.
In that firstly i run file name start-shell.bat . In that i need to install mozilla central. While installing mozilla central ,an error occure "abort: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
please help me to get ride of this error.[image includes command and error of mozilla-central](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM5Gi.png)